# Using bquote to create variable names with dots

Tags: r, functional-programming

In my functional programming I currently use the following code snippet to generate code for a function body.

```
i <- 4
paste("x.", i, " <- state", sep = "")
```

This creates the code `x.4 <- state`. Now, I'd like to change to `bquote()`, but I have no idea to create this code snippet. A

```
i <- 4
bquote(x..(i) <- state)
```

fails, because of the dots.

I use the dots to separate higher orders like `x.12.4`. All other delimiters like `_` or `-` are not allowed in variable names.

Do you have an idea, or is it impossible with the dots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd likely use `substitute()`:

```
i <- 4
substitute(XX <- state, list(XX = as.name(paste0("x.", i))))
# x.4 <- state
```

With `bquote()`, you could do:

```
with(list(XX=as.name(paste0("x.", i))), bquote(.(XX) <- state))
# x.4 <- state
```

But in either case you'll need to construct the name from `"x."` and `i`, as that's not something that `bquote()` does.

Comment: I know `substitute`, but my aim was to modify the code in a minimum way. `bquote` is the right tool for that, except with dots in the variable names.

Comment: @Dirk -- The fact that your desired variable name has a dot in it is actually a red herring here. (`bquote(x.(i) <- state)` doesn't work either.) `bquote()` works by parsing the expression you hand it, and treating specially tokens that **begin** with `.(`. You are expecting it to do much more than that, (a) correctly parsing `x..(i)` to mean `x.` and `.(i)`, (b) substituting in the value of `.(x)`, and then (c) pasting both pieces together. Steps (a) and (c) just aren't supported anywhere in the simple code of `bquote()`.

Comment: So, my fault is using a dot. What do you suggest to be able to distinguish `x.2.11` and `x.21.1`? All other special character might be red herring, too.

Comment: Neither of those terms will undergo any substitution, since they are not wrapped in `.()`.  As for my best suggestions, I gave them in my answer! If you're interested in how `bquote()` works, and what it will do, you might want to do `debug(bquote)`, then call it with your expression of interest, press return twice, then type `debug(unquote)`, then step through the rest of the evaluation by repeatedly pressing return, inspecting `e` within each subloop.